# Elegant way to write ordered comparison on multiple properties

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, comparison, monads

Say I have a data type like the following:

```
data Foo = Foo { field1, field2, field3 :: Int }
```

And I'd like to make it an instance of `Ord` by comparing `field1`, `field2`, and `field3` in a particular order.

I find it very annoying to write:

```
-- (we need Eq Foo to define Ord Foo)
instance Eq Foo where
    x == y = all id [ f x == f y
                    | f <- [field1, field2, field3] ]

instance Ord Foo where
    compare x y = case (comparing field1) x y of
        EQ -> case (comparing field2) x y of
            EQ -> (comparing field3) x y
            ord -> ord
        ord -> ord
```

Monads like `Maybe` and `Either` have some really nice support for this kind of thing, and I find myself wishing that `Ordering` had something similar, e.g.

```
instance Ord Foo where
    compare == comparing field1 >>= comparing field2 >>= comparing field3
```

...or something like that.

I've needed to do this for complex data types, where re-ordering fields in the definition and depending on default definitions for `deriving (Eq, Ord)` were not possible, so I'm not interested in solutions that game the default instance declarations.

Is there a more elegant, or at least more terse, way to define this kind of ordering?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's an unrelated tip: `all id` is the same as `and :: [Bool] -> Bool`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `Monoid` instance for `Ordering` and functions to good effect here:

```
instance Ord Foo where
    compare = comparing field1 <> comparing field2 <> comparing field3
```

Another trick you can use that generalizes more readily to the `Eq` instance is to use the instances for tuples:

```
equating = on (==)
reorder v = (field1 v, field2 v, field3 v)

instance Eq  Foo where (==)    = equating  reorder
instance Ord Foo where compare = comparing reorder
```

Comment: Assuming `field1 :: Num`, how to order by the reverse of `field1`, keeping the rest of the comparisons unaffected? I guess we could do `comparing (negate . field1)`, but I'm curious if it can be done with `Down`.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar There are many ways. Your proposal, `flip (comparing field1)`, `comparing (Down . field1)`, and probably half a dozen others.